# Area of hexagon outside circle

Tags: geometry

Let's have a circle with radius r.

I want to find out the area of the hexagon drawn around the circle. Supplemented is a sample image except I need to whole are of hexagon, not just intersection.

Area of hexagon drawn inside circle is:

`(sqrt3*r)^2`

as far as I know.

[image]

Comment: And what's your problem? The math or the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hexagon consists of 6 equilateral triangles with height R. Area of such triangle is

```
s = R * R * Sqrt(3) / 3
```

Area of hexagon

```
S = 6 * s = 2 * Sqrt(3) * R^2
```

(If you need area of colored region, it is `R^2 * (2 * Sqrt(3) - Pi)`)